# Kion signifas kesito?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning

19Kaj la kampoparton, sur kiu li starigis sian tendon, li aĉetis el la manoj de la filoj de Ĥamor, la patro de Ŝeĥem, por cent **kesitoj**. (Moseo 1: Genezo 33)

Kion signifas kesito? Ĉu ĝi estis antikva valuto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laŭ [biblica.com](https://www.biblica.com/bible/niv/genesis/33/) en la New International Version de la biblio, ĝi estas:

> For a hundred pieces of silver, he bought from the sons of Hamor, the father of Shechem, the plot of ground where he pitched his tent.

Kaj estas noto sub tio:

> Hebrew hundred kesitahs; a kesitah was a unit of money of unknown weight and value.

Do supozeble *kesito* estas prunta vorto farita de *kesitah* kaj ĝi ja estas antikva valuto.

Estas ankaŭ [artikolo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kesitah) pri la vorto ĉe la angla vikipedio.

Ja estas surprize ke la vorto ne aperas en [PIV](http://vortaro.net) kvankam ĝi aperas en Zamenhofa verkaĵo.

Comment: Kio estas PIV?.

Comment: @user64617 Ĝi estas la Plena Ilustrita Vortaro, eble la plej aŭtoritata vortaro de Esperanto. Ĝi estas uzebla rete ĉe [vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net/).